# Using Different Colors In a Chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

***My Code:***

```
<div><canvas id="canvas_line" height="200" width="800"></canvas></div>

<div><canvas id="canvas_bar" height="200" width="800"></canvas></div>

<script>
    var lineChartData = {
        labels : ["14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","22:00"],
        datasets : [
            {
                label: "CPU IDLE",
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : [85,35,65,59,90,81,56,55,40,100]
            }
        ]
    }

    var barChartData = {
            labels : ["12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","22:00"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data : [85,35,65,59,90,81,56,55,40,100]
                }
            ]
        }


        var ctx_line = document.getElementById("canvas_line").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx_line).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });
        var ctx_bar = document.getElementById("canvas_bar").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx_bar).Bar(barCharData, {
            responsive: true
        });
</script>
```

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4q8F.png), everything is grey.

[image: snap]

But I'd like to change the **lineChart**'s `pointColor` and **barChart**'s `fillcolor` to **red** if its data is above *80*, the data below *80* are still grey.

I want it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D2Pz.png), but I don't know how to use different colors in a **canvas**.

[image: this]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>123</title>
  <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/Chart.js/0.2.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="chartCanvas" height="200" width="800"></canvas>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
      var chartData = {
        labels: ["12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","22:00"],
          datasets: [
          {
            data : [85,35,65,59,90,81,56,55,40,100],
          fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
            strokeColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)'
          }
        ]
      }
      var chartCanvas = document.getElementById("chartCanvas").getContext("2d");
      var barChart = new Chart(chartCanvas).Bar(chartData, {responsive: true});
      // Set warning color
      var bars = barChart.datasets[0].bars;
      for(var i = 0; i < bars.length ; i++) {
        if(bars[i].value > 80) {
           bars[i].fillColor = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)";
           bars[i].strokeColor = "rgba(220, 0, 0, 0.5)";
        }
      }
      // Update the chart
      barChart.update(); 
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop to all the bars/points of your chart, check if the value is over 80 and set the color.

Here is an example for the bar chart:

```
var bars = barChart.datasets[0].bars;
for(var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
  if(bars[i].value > 80) {
    bars[i].fillColor = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)";
    bars[i].strokeColor = "rgba(220, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  }
}
// Update the chart
barChart.update();
```

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1NU5/9n2c90gy/) for a working demo.

To set the color on a line chart you just have to iterate over the points instead of the bars:

```
var points = lineChart.datasets[0].points;
```

And of course set the pointColor or whatever you want.

Comment: Linus,thanks! I got it.     But your code doesn't work on my mac.    I've created a new html file and filled it with the same code on the fiddle, colors didn't change.

Comment: But the fiddle worked? You can't just copy it, you have to put this in a document ready callback.

Comment: "error : 123:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"                          `var bars = barChart.datasets[0].bars;`

Comment: You are using a really old version of Chart.js (0.2.0). My provided code was for version 1.x. Just use https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js/1.0.2 and it will work.